# Loop through visualization in power bi

Tags: microsoft-powerbi, data-visualization

So I want to have a visualization that is basically a table form, but with visualizations that loop for each customer, is there a control or visual that I can use to do this in powerbi? Please see the drawing to understand what I mean:

[image: visualisation]

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is a Table with icons driven by Measures - Conditional Formatting.

These can be extended by writing Measures that present images in SVG or base64 encoded format, there's some starter examples in this blog post:

https://exceleratorbi.com.au/conditional-formatting-using-icons-in-power-bi/

However figuring out how to dynamically generate an SVG image is an obscure pro developer task.